# Navigation from native components to React Native components

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation for routing within the react components in the project. But I want to implement like this:

```
React Native Component.click -> Android Java Activity.click -> React Native Component
```

For the first part of navigation, I am implemented an ActivityStarterModule like this [example](https://github.com/petterh/react-native-android-activity)

Can someone suggest how I navigate from Java activity to specific React Component?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout https://github.com/callstack/react-native-brownfield

It has some helpers for integration between native screens and react native screens.